# Stroring Formgroup object in DB

Tags: typescript, angular8, angular-reactive-forms

How to use angular form application object for later use. I am creating angular application where the form has to be rendered dynamically to edit the values that where stored in the DB.

Steps Tried:
 1. Tried storing the form group object in the DB,but got a circular json error.
 2. Tried storing form group json value but since form group value is read-only, will not able to assign json value

Note:
- Tried assigning individual form control values manually which works. Is there any way where i can store and retrieve the form group object for later use(Edit) the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the value of the FormGroup with `formGroup.value` and set it with `formGroup.patchValue(value)`.